# Visual Studio Community 2015 error de instalación

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Instalé Visual Studio Community 2015 en un notebook sin problemas. En otro notebook, también con Windows 7 Service pack 1, x64 bits no he podido instalarlo ni con el web installer ni con la ISO. Me da el error que adjunto en la imagen

Leí los hilos en

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/

y dicen que puede ser la actualización kb2999226 que se cuelga. Probé varias soluciones sin éxito. Desinstalé todo, desactivé el antivirus y ejecuté el instalador con derechos de administrador y de el mismo problema.

**Alguna sugerencia de cómo solucionar este problema de instalación?**

Imagen del error

[image: Imagen del error]

Comment: entiendo que fallan los paquetes que quiere descargar, que pasa si instalas desmarcando estos paquetes con problemas? luego si los necesitas podrias volver agregarlos. Puede que el fallo se de porque no tiene conexion a internet

Comment: @LeandroTuttini NuGet al menos lo necesito. Voy a probar una instalación más personalizada y ver si funciona. Reporto aquí si funcionó.

Comment: pero nuget puedes instalarlo despues, es mas se puede agregar como extension desde el mismo VS

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Por si a alguien más le sirve pude resolver usando un programa de terceros http://download.wsusoffline.net/ al ejecutarlo descarga e instala cantidad de Updates. Si se cuelga hay que seguir ejecutando de nuevo. Después de un par de intentos el Windows Update funciona de nuevo, descarga las actualizaciones y cuando todo está en verde pude Reparar o Instalar Visual Studio sin problemas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si a alguien más le sirve pude resolver usando un programa de terceros download.wsusoffline.net al ejecutarlo descarga e instala cantidad de Updates. Si se cuelga hay que seguir ejecutando de nuevo. Después de un par de intentos el Windows Update funciona de nuevo, descarga las actualizaciones y cuando todo está en verde pude Reparar o Instalar Visual Studio sin problemas! –

La información la encontré en este enlace
https://superuser.com/questions/7261/offline-update-of-windows/115782#115782

Answer (score 1):

Si es con windows 7 es un problema de actualizaciones busca en internet estas dos actualizaciones es algo como el service pack 3 de win7

kb3020369 hay una para 32b y 64b
kb3125574 hay un para 32b y 64b

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pasé a Windows 10 y pudo solucionar!